# Open Crashlytics OSX App manually

Tags: ios, macos, crashlytics

I have implemented `Crashlytics` in my iOS app. But when i archive my app `Crashlytics` OSX app doesn't open.

My question is can we manually open the `Crashlytics` OSX App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, actually `Crashlytics` is a part of `Fabric` ecosystem.
Go to `Applications` folder find `Fabric` app and double click its icon.
[image]

If you are still `Crashlytics` user - then search for `Crashlytics` app inside `Applications` folder.

More info of how to upgrade your account to `Fabric` - you can find [here](https://fabric.io/upgrade)
Or you can [download](https://monosnap.com/file/A6XXuRWgqbis5tm7hgVtcBduh58WoF) `Crashlytics` app from [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

Comment: Well there is no Fabric or Crashlytics App in my Mac. It automatically open sometime when i build my iOS App that has Crashlytics integration.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess you should properly register your app with `Crashlytics` or `Fabric` tool, and after it will install os x app for you.

Comment: It was opening as always but today i force close that app due to system over load and after that it is not opening when ever i try to build or archive any app.
I have tried by changing build and version number also but it doesn't open.

Comment: `It was opening as always` - according to this your comment - does not this mean that you already have such mac app :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You had have to download Fabric-latest.zip from Fabric web page, just unzip it and copy Fabric App in you Applications folders and finally execute it from there.